# Magento: Disable products being added to multiple categories

Tags: magento

Is it possible to disable users from adding products to multiple categories in the catalog? When a user tries to add a product, it shows all the available categories and sub categories 
 in the catalog and if the user selects all of them, the same product will be added all over the place in the store. I was wondering if there's a way to restrict that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to do what you describe natively in Magento, you would have to write a local module.

Comment: I would need something that If, category 1 is selected, then category 2 gets disabled, and viceversa.

Comment: Like I said, that's a feature that doesn't exist natively in Magento, and you'd have to hire a software developer to code it for you. What you're describing isn't exactly a common straightforward modification of Magento's backend, so I'd be surprised if anyone here was willing to do it for free. :)

Comment: I think I'll be able to code it myself.                                            Basically, I would need something like this:            $('album_checkbox_find_abstract_name').observer('changed', function(event){
    if(this.checked) {
        $$('.some_class_around_all_the_checkboxes input[type=checkbox]').each(function(elem) {
            if(elem != this) elem.disabled = true;
        });
    } else {
        $$('.some_class_around_all_the_checkboxes input[type=checkbox]').each(function(elem) {
            elem.disabled = false;
        });
    }
});

Comment: I guess you could do it with JavaScript, but remember that products can be assigned to categories in a number of different places and different ways. You'll have to account for all of them.

Comment: True that. I just found this:                                                                   function cbChange(obj) {
    var cbs = document.getElementsByClassName("wk_elements");
    for (var i = 0; i < cbs.length; i++) {
        cbs[i].checked = false;
    }
    obj.checked = true;                                                                 Trying to implement it but it is not working so far. And this is for the frontend of my store as it is multi seller.

Comment: I fixed this myself. Thanks anyway.